# Comment traduire le concept de « bullet journal » ?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, anglais

> Un usage contemporain du calepin est le [*bullet journal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullet_Journal) [« Bullet Journals are usually handwritten, and kept in a single notebook »], concept
>   d’organiseur mis au point par Ryder Caroll au début des années 2010<sup>[6](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calepin#cite_note-6)</sup>.
>   (Wikipédia, [*calepin*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calepin))

Des explications peuvent aider à comprendre pourquoi on a « bullet » :

> If Rapid Logging is language the BuJo is written in, Bullets are the
>   syntax. Bullets are short-form sentences paired with symbols that
>   visually categorize your entries into: Tasks, Events, or Notes. [...] ([bulletjournal.com](https://bulletjournal.com/pages/learn))

Donc il s'agit d'une [*puce*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puce_(typographie)) particulière accompagnée d'une phrase. Au pluriel on connaît sans doute *aux puces* (*marché*, par exemple), de sens différent qu'en typographie. Évidemment quand on veut évoquer le concept de Caroll on peut l'employer tel quel (*bullet journal*, comme [ici](http://madame.lefigaro.fr/societe/le-bullet-journal-pourquoi-ce-carnet-va-vous-changer-la-vie-180816-115872)), mais j'aimerais savoir comment on traduit en évitant les connotations de brocante, voire d'insecte...

Answer (score 1):

> Journal à signets
>
> Bloc-notes à icônes
>
> Calepin à symboles

On peut croiser les réponses.